# how to use uidatepickerview in timer?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to use timer with UIDatePickerView? 
What I want to write code?

Pls help me.

Comment: Can you give some more Explanation what you want to do exactly

Comment: @user633608 Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Change mode of `UIDatePickerView` to timer....Do as i had done below

```
// Add the picker
    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,0,0)];
    [pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];

    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];

    [pickerView release];
```

Good Luck!